# Как можно сериализовать все переменные статического класса?

Tags: c#, классы, сериализация

Есть статический класс WorkingClass, созданный специально для обратной связи между элементами приложения

```
        public static class WorkingClass
    {
        public static List<Book> books = new List<Book> { };
        public static List<Member> members = new List<Member> { };
        public static Book b;
        public static Member member;
        public static bool okTitle = false;
        public static bool okISBN = false;
        public static bool okAuthor = false;
        public static bool change = false;
        public static int indexOfbook = 0;
        public static int indexOfmemb = 0;
        public static bool newBook = false;
        public static bool newMember = false;
        public static bool ok1 = false;
        public static bool ok2 = false;
        public static bool ok3 = false;
        public static bool ok4 = false;
        public static CopyBook copyBook;
        public static int indexOfcopy;
}
```

Как можно сериализовать все эти данные?
Каждую переменную можно сериализовать по отдельности,а сразу все никак?

Язык C#,проект WinForms

Comment: Приложите код к вопросу.

Comment: Никак, делайте класс нестатическим. Если должен существовать только один экземпляр этого класса — сделайте его синглтоном. И, кстати, почему бы не воспользоваться стандартными `Settings`?

Comment: Можно, конечно, что-то придумать используя рефлексию, но я не думаю, что это хорошее решение (хотя сериализация в итоге все равно ее использует). В любом случае, если есть возможность отказаться от глобального состояния (коим является статический класс), вы должны это сделать.

Comment: @Артем приложил

Comment: @Андрей но ведь можно сериализовать каждую переменную по отдельности...А все сразу никак?(

Comment: @deced тут суть в том, что невозможно создать экземпляр статического класса. На то статические члены и созданы, что они вне экземпляров. В статическом классе все члены статические.

Comment: @Андрей чем можно заменить статический класс для тех же нужд?

Comment: Ну я ж вам выше написал *делайте класс нестатическим*

Comment: Статическим должен быть сам экземпляр класса (т.е. поле, которое его хранит), а не отдельные его члены. Так будет намного проще все это провернуть.

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight можно пожалуйста подробнее как это провернуть?

Comment: @deced возможно вам нужно переосмыслить логику вашего приложения, это сейчас у вас данных N байт, а когда библиотека ваших книг начнёт расширятся - статические члены и классы дадут о себе знать. Я вообще использовал-бы `Dictionary<string>,<myClass>` данные хранил бы в `json`.  А вызывал бы нужный мне `myClass` так `var data = Dictioary[key].books`, здесь статичен только `Dictonary`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Буквально поставленная задача решается с помощью Reflection в сочетании с функциональностью сериализации коллекций в XML-тип `ArrayOfAnyType`. Как-то так:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Reflection;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

namespace WinformsTest
{
    public static class WorkingClass
    {
        //несколько полей разных типов для примера...
        public static int a=0;
        public static string b = "Hello";
        public static List<string> c = new List<string> { "Петр","Мария","Александр" };

        //Сохраняет состояние всех статических полей текущего класса в XML-файл
        public static void Save(string file)
        {
            List<object> values = new List<object>(); 
            List<Type> types = new List<Type>(); 
            types.Add(typeof(string));

            //найдем все статические поля
            FieldInfo[] vars = typeof(WorkingClass).GetFields(
                    BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static
                    );

            //занесем все в коллекцию и найдем все возможные типы
            foreach (FieldInfo x in vars)
            {
                values.Add(x.Name);
                values.Add(x.GetValue(null)); 
                if (!types.Contains(x.FieldType)) types.Add(x.FieldType); 
            }

            //сериализуем коллекцию в файл 
            XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<object>), types.ToArray());

            Stream s = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Create);

            using (s)
            {
                ser.Serialize(s, values);
            }
        }

        //Считывает состояние всех статических полей текущего класса из XML-файла
        public static void Load(string file)
        {
            List<object> values;
            List<Type> types = new List<Type>();
            types.Add(typeof(string));

            //найдем все статические поля
            FieldInfo[] vars = typeof(WorkingClass).GetFields(
                    BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Static
                    );

            //найдем все возможные типы
            foreach (FieldInfo x in vars)
            {                
                if(!types.Contains(x.FieldType)) types.Add(x.FieldType);
            }

            //загружаем коллекцию из файла
            XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<object>), types.ToArray());
            Stream s = new FileStream(file, FileMode.Open);

            using (s)
            {
                values = (List<object>)ser.Deserialize(s);
            }            

            for(int i =0 ; i<values.Count;i+=2)
            {
                var item = vars.Where(x => x.Name == (string)values[i]).First(); //найдем поле по имени

                if (item != null)
                {
                    item.SetValue(null, values[i + 1]); //установим значение поля
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Получаемый XML выглядит так:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ArrayOfAnyType xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">a</anyType>
  <anyType xsi:type="xsd:int">0</anyType>
  <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">b</anyType>
  <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">Hello</anyType>
  <anyType xsi:type="xsd:string">c</anyType>
  <anyType xsi:type="ArrayOfString">
    <string>Петр</string>
    <string>Мария</string>
    <string>Александр</string>
  </anyType>
</ArrayOfAnyType>
```

---

Однако, на практике принято все делать немного по другому. Использование статических открытых переменных для хранения данных предметной области, помимо наличия обычных для "глобального состояния" проблем с масштабируемостью приложения, затрудняет синхронизацию доступа из разных потоков и разработку GUI. Вместо этого, лучше сделать нормальный класс и специальное статическое поле для "основного" экземпляра:

```
public class WorkingClass
{
    public bool a {get;set;}
    public int b {get;set;}
    public Book c {get;set;}
    //....

    static WorkingClass _Instance = new WorkingClass();

    public static WorkingClass Instance 
    {
      get { return _Instance; }
    }
}
```

Тогда можно сериализовывать экземпляр *_Instance* штатными средствами. Обращаться к переменным из любого места программы можно через `WorkingClass.Instance.a`. Раз любой доступ к данным осуществляется через геттер одного свойства, при таком подходе легко обеспечить синхронизацию потоков и уведомление GUI об изменениях.